# Grouping fields together

Tags: 7, entities

Is it possible to generate fields which are "grouped" together when marked as Unlimited? For example, a select field with label "What time do you wake up?" lets the user select the day of the week (Mon-Sun) then beside it an empty textfield to type in the time they get up. These 2 fields are "grouped" together. Then if they want to add another day of the week (Unlimited), the new field generates a dropdown menu and a textfield together all over again.

NOTE: No CCK please. I'm using Drupal 7 and it's already in the core.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module. It's not stable yet (beta 1) but it looks promising.

Comment: I'll check it out.

Comment: Stupid question but how do I use Field Collection? I just installed it.

Comment: You can download the recruiter distribution to see how it's implemented. Other wise the field collections or like nodes (entities) that you can add to the actual node as a field for each collection. So, make a bunch of collections like they are their own node, then make a node and add the collections which are individual fields.

Answer (score 0):

I know the Drupal way to build a module that solves everybody's problems but I needed something a little more specific. Here is my business [hours module](https://github.com/adam-s/hours/blob/master/hours.module). I made it with the Field API which is actually very easy to use.

Comment: IMO there is nothing wrong with a well written custom module that uses the API as intended. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

This is actuall a feature in CCK 3, which is in alpha for D6 but not yet available (as an "extras" module) for D7...

Shame, they should've had this by default.

Here is a discussion about modules that have similar functionality:

http://drupal.org/node/939836

But Field collection seems to be the smartest choice for now.

Comment: While OP has specified no CCK solutions, it is nice to have them.